# JavaScript OnChange load another JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a Jsp page on which there is a form `form1` with a dropdownlist and I have included another Jsp page containing another form `form2` to this page. I want that the `form2` should be visible only when a particular `element(say opt2)` on the dropdownlist of `form1` is *selected*.

Please see the code structure below:

```
<div id="somediv1">
    <%@ include file="../form2.jsp"%>
</div>
<form id="form1">
    <select  id="list1">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
    <option>opt3</option>
    <option>opt4</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
// hide the form on start
$( "#somediv1" ).hide();

if( $( "#list1 option:selected" ).text() == "opt2" ){
    $( "#somediv1" ).show();
} else {
    $( "#somediv1" ).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jQuery's `toggle()` method if you're into the whole brevity thing.

Complete example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#list1").on('change', function(){
        $("#somediv1").toggle( $(this).find("option:selected").text() == "opt2") );    
    })
    .trigger('change'); //trigger the change handler to set the initial state of #someDiv1
});
```